# HttpClient doesn't send a response

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, webapi

This is the code I have so far:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/search-music")]
        public async Task<List<SongFilterPreview>> GetSongs([FromUri] string searchTerm)
        {
            var token = await ServiceContext.TokenService.isAccessTokenExpired();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(searchURL);
            builder.Query = "type=searchByValue&&searchTerm=" + searchTerm;
          
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            HttpResponseMessage message = client.GetAsync(builder.Uri).Result;

            string result = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dynamic items = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<object>>(result);

            List<SongFilterPreview> songs = new List<SongFilterPreview>();
            foreach(var item in items)
            {
                var sfp = new SongFilterPreview()
                {
                    songId = item["id"],
                    songName = item["title"],
                    Performer = item["group"],
                    songUrl = await CreateMediaUrl(item["id"])
                    
                };
                songs.Add(sfp);
            }
            return songs;
        }


 public async Task<string> CreateMediaUrl(int songId)
        {
           
            var playToken = await ServiceContext.TokenService.isPlayTokenExpired();
            var objectData = new
              {
                  playToken = playToken,
                  secure = true
              };

             HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
             client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://apis.tunify.com/t4-media-service/zone/529155/track/" + songId + "/media-url/");
             client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjUyOTE1NSwiem9uZUlkIjo1MjkxNTUsImFwcElkIjo2NSwiY2xpZW50X2lkIjoiNjUiLCJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6WyJSRUFEX1BSSVZJTEVHRSJdLCJzY29wZSI6WyJyZWFkIl0sImlhdCI6MTYxNDc3MDUwMSwiZXhwIjoxNjE0ODQyNTAxfQ.xmooyG3oFccoDNsTEsWlloLhAm0DgIw0_GFJ1uLXkZk");
             var content = new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objectData), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
             var message = await client.PostAsync("https://apis.tunify.com/t4-media-service/zone/529155/track/" + songId + "/media-url/", content);

           
            string result = message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dynamic item = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<object>(result);

             var oneUrl = "";
             foreach (var url in item)
             {
                 oneUrl = url["url"];
             }

            return oneUrl;
        }
```

I want iterate through the list of songs and fetch the url for each song, but my application doesn't send me response. I know what the problem is, it is CreateMediaUrl
(client.SendPost) but I don't know who to fix it. when i send request from postman, i just can see "Sending request". How can i fix this?

Comment: Don't use `.Result`, you should be `await`ing the tasks.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Don't use `JavaScriptSerializer` either. That's an obsolete class used used as a stop-gap 10 years ago. It doesn't support the JSON conventions introduced since, eg the ISO8601 format for dates. Even ASP.NET Web API used Json.NET before it was replaced by System.Text.Json.

Comment: It's really not clear what your error is anyway. "doesn't send me response" - what does that mean? Have you tried stepping through your code? Is the `GetSongs` method useful here, if not then remove it from this post. We need a [mre]

Comment: @user237 the code you posted has several obvious problems. They may not be directly related to your current problem, but they **have** to be fixed. Using `.Result` in an async method is pointless - that's why you added `async` in the first place, to be able to use `await.` Using `JavaScriptSerializer` will fail with JSON strings that use proper dates.

Comment: @user237 besides, HttpClient doesn't send responses, it sends *requests* and receives responses.

Comment: @DavidG What should I use instead of JavaScriptSerializer? I want convert json object to custom object

Comment: @DavidG HttpClient doesn't create url for each song

Comment: Maybe remove the base address when you are already sending the absolute uri in post.